# Referencing translation inside of another translation

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I have this situation:

```
unit:
    sqkm: Square Kilometers

my_translation: Size is %size% ## I want to append the value of unit.sqkm here ##
```

Is there a way to reference the translation of the `unit.sqkm` inside the `my_translation` key?

**Edit**: Please note that i do know how i can do this via twig. My question is: **is there a way to do this in the translation files**.

Comment: Did you find a way to do with within your translation files?

Answer (score 2):

I extended Symfony Tanslator for this:

```
<?php

namespace Bundle\Program\Translation;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Translation\Translator as BaseTranslator;

class Translator extends BaseTranslator
{
    /**
     * Uses Symfony Translator to translate, but enables referencing other translations via @@code@@
     */
    public function trans($id, array $parameters = array(), $domain = null, $locale = null)
    {
        $text = parent::trans($id, $parameters, $domain, $locale);

        $translations = [];

        $delimiter = "@@";
        $strLen = strlen($delimiter);
        $pos = strpos($text, $delimiter);

        while ($pos !== false) {
            $startsAt = $pos + $strLen;
            $endsAt = strpos($text, $delimiter, $startsAt);
            $translations[] = $delimiter . substr($text, $startsAt, $endsAt - $startsAt) . $delimiter;
            $pos = strpos($text, $delimiter, $endsAt + $strLen);
        }

        foreach ($translations as $translation) {
            $translationTrim = str_replace($delimiter, '', $translation);
            $text = str_replace($translation, $this->trans($translationTrim, $parameters, $domain, $locale), $text);
        }

        return $text;
    }
}
```

Then replace the Symfony translator class via parameters:

```
parameters:

    translator.class: Bundle\Program\Translation\Translator
```

Now you can reference other translations via @@other.translation@@ INSIDE your yml file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use translated values inside other translations.

```
{{ 'paragraph' | trans({ '%size%': 3, '%unit%': 'unit' | trans()}) }}
```

Where `unit` itself is another key for a translation. Your translation file however could look like this:

```
paragraph: Size is %size% %unit%
unit: Square Kilometers
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i want to do that inside my translation files, not in the view.

Comment: @devsheeep This is useful to achieve the same result through Twig, however the OP asked for a solution for the translation files.

Answer (score 1):

In your Twig template, try this :

```
{{ 'my_translation' | trans({'%size%': size, 'unit.sqkm' : ('unit.sqkm'|trans)}) }}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i want to do that inside my translation files, not in the view.

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, you want to **achieve this in Symfony 4.1**, here's your solution
(*many thanks to [@Kim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2396925/kim)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45729921/8179249) and [@Aurelijus Rozenas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/846432/aurelijus-rozenas)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40564711/8179249), all credits -apart my 4 hours trying that- go to them*)

First, create your new Translator class (here: **src/Common/ReferenceTranslator.php**)
*I can't manage to find a solution where I would extend the base translator class straight in the class code, let me know if you have one*

```
# src/Common/ReferenceTranslator.php
namespace App\Common;

use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorBagInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface;

class ReferenceTranslator implements TranslatorInterface, TranslatorBagInterface
{
    /** @var TranslatorBagInterface|TranslatorInterface */
    protected $translator;

    /**
     * @param TranslatorInterface|TranslatorBagInterface $translator
     */
    public function __construct($translator)
    {
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }

    /**
     * Uses Symfony Translator to translate, but enables referencing other translations via @@code@@
     * @param $id
     * @param array $parameters
     * @param null $domain
     * @param null $locale
     * @return mixed|string
     */
    public function trans($id, array $parameters = array(), $domain = null, $locale = null)
    {
        $text = $this->translator->trans($id, $parameters, $domain, $locale);

        $translations = [];

        $delimiter = "@@";
        $strLen = strlen($delimiter);
        $pos = strpos($text, $delimiter);

        while ($pos !== false) {
            $startsAt = $pos + $strLen;
            $endsAt = strpos($text, $delimiter, $startsAt);
            $translations[] = $delimiter . substr($text, $startsAt, $endsAt - $startsAt) . $delimiter;
            $pos = strpos($text, $delimiter, $endsAt + $strLen);
        }

        foreach ($translations as $translation) {
            $translationTrim = str_replace($delimiter, '', $translation);
            $text = str_replace($translation, $this->trans($translationTrim, $parameters, $domain, $locale), $text);
        }

        return $text;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $id
     * @param int    $number
     * @param array  $parameters
     * @param null   $domain
     * @param null   $locale
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function transChoice($id, $number, array $parameters = [], $domain = null, $locale = null)
    {    
        return $this->translator->transChoice($id, $number, $parameters, $domain, $locale);
    }

    /**
     * @param string $locale
     */
    public function setLocale($locale)
    {
        $this->translator->setLocale($locale);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLocale()
    {
        return $this->translator->getLocale();
    }

    /**
     * @param string|null $locale
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Translation\MessageCatalogueInterface
     */
    public function getCatalogue($locale = null)
    {
        return $this->translator->getCatalogue($locale);
    }
}
```

And then edit your **services.yaml** file

```
# app/config/services.yml

    #[...]

services:

    #[...]

    # Custom Translator (References)
    # Overrides the Translator Service (is still available as @app.decorating_translator.inner)
    app.decorating_translator:
        class:     App\Common\ReferenceTranslator
        decorates: translator
        arguments:
            - '@app.decorating_translator.inner'
        public:    false
```

And voilà !
Again, don't hesitate if you know how to improve this, as I'm not a Symfony expert !

Answer (score 0):

The TBG answer works,
for Symfony 4.4 here is the code in service.yaml

```
Services
    App\Common\ReferenceTranslator:
        arguments:
            $translator: '@translator'
```

And dont forget to implement *LocaleAwareInterface* too !