# Replacing the Translator service in Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony

In my Symfony 2.8 project I have an extension that adds some extra logic to the **trans** method:

```
parameters:
    translator.class: MyBundle\Twig\TranslationExtension
```

The class looks like this:

```
namespace MyBundle\Twig\TranslationExtension;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Translation\Translator as BaseTranslator;

class TranslationExtension extends BaseTranslator
{
    private $currentLocale;

    public function trans($id, array $parameters = array(), $domain = null, $locale = null)
    {
            $translation = parent::trans($id, $parameters, $domain, $locale);

            // Some extra logic here

            return $translation;
    }

    public function transChoice($id, $number, array $parameters = array(), $domain = null, $locale = null)
    {
        return parent::transChoice($id, $number, $parameters, $domain, $locale);
    }
}
```

Now, I'm migrating to Symfony 3, where those class parameters are deprecated, but how can I implement this by overwriting the **translator** service?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of extending, it would be better to decorate the `translator` service. Right now you overriding the class name, which will also override other bundles that want to decorate the service. And I see you made it an extension because of Twig, the original Twig `{{ trans() }}` filter will use the decorated service too.

```
services:
  app.decorating_translator:
    class:     AppBundle\DecoratingTranslator
    decorates: translator
    arguments: ['@app.decorating_translator.inner'] # original translator
    public:    false
```

See documentation about decorating here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html

Answer (score 9):

Here is full working example how to decorate translator service in symfony 3 and replace parameter in all translated strings.

Decorate service in config:

```
# app/config/services.yml
app.decorating_translator:
    class:     AppBundle\Translation\Translator
    decorates: translator
    arguments:
        - '@app.decorating_translator.inner'
        # passing custom parameters
        - {'%%app_name%%': '%app_name%', '%%PRETTY_ERROR%%': 'This is not nice:'}
    public:    false
```

Create new translator that reuses original translator and adds parameters defined in service config. The only new code is `updateParameters()` method and call to it:

```
# AppBundle/Translation/Translator.php
namespace AppBundle\Translation;

use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorBagInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface;

class Translator implements TranslatorInterface, TranslatorBagInterface
{
    /** @var TranslatorBagInterface|TranslatorInterface */
    protected $translator;
    /** @var array */
    private $parameters;

    /**
     * @param TranslatorInterface|TranslatorBagInterface $translator
     * @param array                                      $parameters
     */
    public function __construct($translator, $parameters)
    {
        $this->translator = $translator;
        $this->parameters = $parameters;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $id
     * @param array  $parameters
     * @param null   $domain
     * @param null   $locale
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function trans($id, array $parameters = [], $domain = null, $locale = null)
    {
        $parameters = $this->updateParameters($parameters);

        return $this->translator->trans($id, $parameters, $domain, $locale);
    }

    /**
     * @param string $id
     * @param int    $number
     * @param array  $parameters
     * @param null   $domain
     * @param null   $locale
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function transChoice($id, $number, array $parameters = [], $domain = null, $locale = null)
    {
        $parameters = $this->updateParameters($parameters);

        return $this->translator->transChoice($id, $number, $parameters, $domain, $locale);
    }

    /**
     * @param string $locale
     */
    public function setLocale($locale)
    {
        $this->translator->setLocale($locale);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLocale()
    {
        return $this->translator->getLocale();
    }

    /**
     * @param string|null $locale
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Translation\MessageCatalogueInterface
     */
    public function getCatalogue($locale = null)
    {
        return $this->translator->getCatalogue($locale);
    }

    /**
     * @param array $parameters
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function updateParameters($parameters)
    {
        return array_merge($this->parameters, $parameters);
    }
}
```

Now every time you translate message `%app_config%` will replaced with parameter from config (e.g. parameters.yml) and `%PRETTY_ERROR%` will be replace with static string.
If needed it is possible to override same parameters when calling trans:

`{{ 'layout.title.home'|trans({'%app_name%': 'Real App No. 1'}) }}`

*Read about service decoration [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html)*

Answer (score 0):

@Aurelijus Rozenas:

add this in your Translator:

```
public function __call($method, $args)
{
    return \call_user_func_array(array($this->translator, $method), $args);
}
```