# Override translator class not working in symfony3

Tags: php, symfony, overriding

I need to know how to override the trans method in symfony3.

In symfony2 project we used to override the parameter for the translator class

```
parameters:
    translator.class: Acme\HelloBundle\Translation\Translator
```

We started using symfony3 and try to apply the same approach but unfortunately the [parameter was removed](https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/commit/3777050007e7dfef257087ef1f954a8cc7c27883) and the class path is written directly into the service.

Answer (score 1):

You can override an existing definition (e.g. when applying the [Decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)). This  kind of decoration is supported by the Dependency Injection Container of Symfony as described [in the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html). As example:

```
services:
    app.mailer:
        class: AppBundle\Mailer

    # this replaces the old app.mailer definition with the new one, the
    # old definition is lost
    app.mailer:
        class: AppBundle\DecoratingMailer
```

and:

```
services:
    # ...

    app.decorating_mailer:
      class:     AppBundle\DecoratingMailer
      decorates: app.mailer
      arguments: ['@app.decorating_mailer.inner']
      public:    false
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks so much, but unfortunately I get wrong argument exception.

**Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Translation\Translator::__construct() must implement interface Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface, none given**

shouldn't the decorator get the same arguments from the original service? or should I pass them again in the new one knowing I extend the original translator class.

also I tried it but I couldn't map the xml schema to yaml

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you solve it? @GehadMohamed

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39470596/replacing-the-translator-service-in-symfony-3/52720929#40564711 you have to completly rewrite the custom Translator for decorator pattern. Extending is not possible with this config.